# Liquibase and functional index

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, h2, liquibase

If you try to execute a script to create a functional index on the H2 (PostgreSQL-oriented context) when using Liquibase, a suspicious error occurs.

The script itself looks like this:

```
    <changeSet id="2" author="...">
        <createIndex tableName="test_table" indexName="test_table_id_idx">
            <column name="(date_trunc('day', create_date))"/>
        </createIndex>
    </changeSet>
```

Error message:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE INDEX TEST_TABLE_ID_IDX ON TEST_TABLE(([*]DATE_TRUNC('day', CREATE_DATE)))"; expected "identifier"; 
SQL statement: CREATE INDEX test_table_id_idx ON test_table((date_trunc('day', create_date))) [42001-200]
```

[PoC on GitHub](https://github.com/inkarnadin/liquibase-h2-index-poc)

To be honest, I do not have ideas from where such a strange supplement of the script appears (about this `[*]`). Perhaps H2 does not understand which field you need to use and substitutes Vilcard or something like that.

Yes, I know about possible collisions and differences in the implementation of H2 and the real PostgreSQL (if that, on the PostgreSQL script is performed correctly), but I would like to understand what causes the generation of such a change of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[*]` in error messages from H2 marks a position where a syntax error was found. H2 does't support indexes on expressions, you can index only columns.

H2 supports indexes on computed columns, so it is possible to add a computed column with your function, index it, and use this computed column in queries instead of function on base column, in that case this index can be used. But I think it isn't your intention if your primary database system is PostgreSQL. If you use H2 only for some tests, it is more reasonable to remove creation of such incompatible indexes from changesets for H2.

Comment: It looks like you are absolutely right. I checked it on pure H2 - yes, the asterisk is an error marker. However, this is a rather strange error marker, given that it can be perceived ambiguously.

And you are right - to solve the problem, the context is really used in relation to the DBMS. The error was only interesting for academic purposes.

Thanks for helping me figure it out.